# Focus a field by selecting an option

Tags: jquery

I want to set focus on a field when I select an option but it's not woking. The focus is not applied to the desired input field. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name=selector]').change(function () {
        if($(this).val() == 'a'){
            $("#new").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `$('new')` selector isn't right. Presumably you're missing a `#` or `.` prefix for an id or class...? Voting to close as a typo as besides that what you have should work fine.

Comment: edit: 'new' is an 'id' of the input field.

Comment: Thanks @Rory. But that is okay for me, just a typo over here.

Comment: In which case your code works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vrLdjfae/. Please check the console for errors

Comment: Not working in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: Then there must be another part of your code affecting it, as you can see from the fiddle, what you have shown us works absolutely fine. Is the `select` element dynamically added to the page?

Comment: Yes, option values are added dynamically. But here is a note, its working fine when I'm using val(), or enable/disable functionality. Not working only for focus()

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement this on change of select tag as you are doing and can focus on input box by `$('#new').focus()` if new is the id of inputbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selector').change(function(){
         if($(this).val()=='a'){
            $('#new').focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
<option value="d">D</option>
<option value="e">E</option>
</select>
<input id="new" name="new" value="" />
```